# InstallShield add custom action to check for anti-virus

Tags: installation, installshield

I am a bit of a beginner at InstallShield (in the sense that this is the first time I've used it!).

I have some code that I am packaging up in a .net DLL to check for the existence of anti-virus. The installer I am attempting to create must check for anti-virus (by calling a custom action using my DLL?) and cancel the install if none has been found.

The way I seen it working, was the user would see a dialog that is informational ("about to check for anti-virus"), the user would press "Next" it would call the custom action and then show a success screen with a "Next" button, or a failure screen with "Finish" button.

Is this sort of thing possible with InstallShield? Are there any good tutorials out there for doing this sort of thing?

Comment: Why would you want to do it? Users are free either use anti-virus or not. I would be really upset if an application didn't allow me to install it because I don't have an anti-virus (yet). I would hardly return to such an application later or ever recommend it to anyone.

Comment: This is a business application for companies that we have, and we provide support for it. And we are enforcing anti-virus. Not getting into the reasons behind it, but anti-virus is a must :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need a custom action?  Do you have more detailed requirements with regards to what products and versions you are looking for?

InstallShield / Windows Installer has a built in search pattern that can look for registry entries, files, et al.

If you really do need a custom action, how long do you expect the execution to take? If it's only a couple seconds, just schedule it to run after AppSearch.  You don't need a UI to say "now doing blah"  just do it.

Since you want to do this in .NET, you need to look at Windows Installer XML (WiX) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF).   You can use this to author/compile custom action DLL's that InstallShield can then consume.  Generally the custom action should do it's search and then set a property based on it's result.  Then use that property in evaluating whatever business rule you are trying to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am only looking for the existence of ANY antivirus, not a specific one. I am using WMI to get to this info and have written C# code to get it. My requirement is to check for it, and advise the user if none is detected and halt the install. What would you suggest?

Comment: My suggestion is the same then. Put the code into a C# DTF custom action scheduled between AppSearch and LaunchConditions.  Have the C# code query wmi and set a property based on the results.  Then use a launch condition to block the install based on the property.

Comment: Ok thanks, all of that makes sense, I will do a bit of googling now to see how I actually do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One issue, was that the user needs to be warned about the fact no anti-virus is installed before cancelling, would your method do this?

Comment: yes, read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369751(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I have marked your answer as the answer. However due to the complexity of the installer that I am building I am changing it to be created fully by installscript within install shield, so I have created a custom dll call that way and let my installscript deal with it.